# How to get thread.sleep to work

Tags: java

In my code below im am tring to add a thread.sleep for when someone chooses the option to exit the lift, i am not sure whats wrong with the code i entered to make it sleep.I already included the Interrupted exception so can someone tell me where i went wrong.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class username{

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

        String[] verifiedNames = { "barry", "matty", "olly", "joey" };
        System.out.println("choose an option");
        System.out.println("Uselift(1)");
        System.out.println("see audit report(2)");
        System.out.println("Exit Lift(3)");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
            scanner.nextLine(); // get '\n' symbol from previous input
            int nameAttemptsLeft = 3;
            while (nameAttemptsLeft-- > 0) {
                System.out.println(" Enter your name ");
                String name = scanner.nextLine();

                if (Arrays.asList(verifiedNames).contains(name)) {
                    System.out.println("dear " + name + " you are verified " +
                    "you may use the lift, calling lift ");
                    break; // break out of loop
                }
            }
            if (nameAttemptsLeft < 0) {
                System.out.println("Username Invalid");
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            System.out.println("option 2");
            break;
            case 3:
            System.out.println(" Please Exit Lift ");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: when the third case is chosen, after it says exit the lift, i want it to sleep for 5 seconds and then system.exit will terminate the program

Comment: Try Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);

Comment: @JHollanti No. `sleep` is a `static` method.

Comment: try ` try {
   Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: none of the have worked "please exit lift" has came up instantly everytime

Comment: I don't know if `main(String... args)` is valid. Try using `main(String[] args)`

Comment: String... args is the same thing as String[] args, String... just means "treat all parameters past this point as part of an array declaration".

OP, if you just want "please exit lift" to come up after a delay, move the thread.sleep to BEFORE the print.

Answer (score 1):

You're ending your program after the `sleep` returns.

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.exit(0);
```

Maybe you're looking for a loop of some kind. You haven't shown us what comes after the `switch`, but maybe that `System.exit(0)`, which stops the java process, shouldn't be there.

Comment: i actually would like it to loop back to the start of the program again after so i maybe should change it to system.close?, but i am not sure how to do that, however i still need the delay to represent the time it takes the doors to close so a person can exit the lift safely etc. @Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `System.exit(0)`

Wrap your method in a loop if you want it to loop. My example is an infinite loop, but if your application accepts user input you can just as easily have a boolean flag that serves as the loop condition.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    while(true){
    //all of your code
    }
}
```

Also you should surround your sleep in a try-catch instead of declaring a throws on your main method... it is good practice to catch exceptions you can handle, and throw exceptions that you cannot handle to earlier stack frames that can. Typically you don't want your main() method to have a throws clause as it can cause the premature termination of your application. This doesn't really matter for `InterruptedException` in your specific case, but does for many other exceptions.